# Better editor for customizing VS 2010 menus?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, menu, customization, development-environment, toolbar

Can't STAND the editor for configuring Visual Studio 2010's environment menus.  It's soo freaking tedious now!  Just try creating a sub-menu, or even adding several commands to your own toolbar.  You have to do it one.  Command.  At.  A.  Time. closing the command window each time, then losing your place and having to start over again.

Does anyone know of any add-in or extension that lets you actually drag-drop menus and commands so you can more easily set up your enviro the way you want?

Right now, it's such a pain that half the time I just don't even bother.